# iOS - Javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone

Im trying to get Javascript to work on an iphone.
The way Im opening the html document is by sending it via email as an attachment and simply open it.

this is the code:

```
<script>
function setText()
{
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = 'This is a test';
}
</script>
<p id="txt">This text will change</p><BR>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click me" onClick="setText()"/>
```

Works great in Internet explorer and chrome but clicking the button on iphone does absolutely nothing.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you please tell a use case?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/38944/can-i-save-an-html-file-to-my-iphone-and-open-in-safari

Comment: Are you reading this message from the default mail client? A web client? What else? Which browser? Safari?

Comment: Its a different mail client but it opens in Safari. My goal eventually is to have a function that calculates a number I will generate and print it. But first I want to be able to print anything..

Comment: What do you mean by "mail client but it opens in Safari"? Is it a web app running in browser?

Comment: OK, it doesn't open in safari.. My bad on that.. Any idea how I get it to run from an email attachment?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is sending this as an HTML email not an attachement. More on how to do that https://www.thoughtco.com/how-to-send-html-email-3468764